# Custom Javascript code in a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would need to add a javascript code within a specific page of my wordpress site.
I would like to find a solution via plugin, otherwise maybe I could modify the code I already use specifying the page, but I don't know how to do it

This is my code:

```
( function( $ )  {

    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.title_subtitle_holder_inner > h1:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)').text('EVENTI');
    });

})( jQuery );
```

I would need that text to be edited on a specific page, in my case the page id would be 217

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably no harm in injecting that minimal code into all pages, just make it so that it selects elements only when on your specific target page.

WordPress creates a class `page-id-XY` on the `body` element automatically, so just prepend your selector accordingly, so that it will only select elements on that specific page:

```
$('body.page-id-217 .title_subtitle_holder_inner > h1:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)')
```

Comment: This is a really clever solution, but it doesn't work.
Probably because the page is self-generated by the "The Event Calendar" plugin.

Comment: What _kind_ of page is it, an archive page or something? When you check the classes on the body element in the source code, what else do you find there? Something like `post-type-archive-event` or similar might exist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved it.

It was an archive page and the linked id was 0, although in the dashboard it reported as id page 217, I don't know why.

You gave me the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-specific-scripts/

Or any other method for custom scripts on specific page. From what I recall I think WordPress has this functionality built in.

Comment: Thank you, it was the first solution I found, but it doesn't work.